# tooltip to show at top of tooltip icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement where i have multiple tables in a page and when i mouse over on one column it has to show tooltip at the top position with some data in it. Issue is tooltip is showing randomly. Tooltip data should appear immediate top of the tooltip icon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u try adding something like `z-index:1000;` to `a.tooltip span`?

Comment: Do the tables have overflow: hidden ?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter--I tried z-index but it didn't helped.

Comment: @ TimSPQR - No tables dont have overflow: hidden , i explicitly gave overflow:visible and checked but still could not able to see the extra hidden tooltip data.

Comment: @participantjava can u take a piece of rendered HTML + CSS and recreate the issue in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I change the position on this class `a.tooltip:hover span` from `fixed` to `absolute` and seems fix the problem at least in fiddle. And change the position to be top.

Top:
http://jsfiddle.net/EK54x/2/

Beneath:
http://jsfiddle.net/EK54x

Comment: Alek, one more point where i got stuck,  i have a table for each column in table when i mouse over it has to show tooltip with some data in it, issue is for the first row the tool tip data is not completely visible as it hiding benath the header i believe. Can we write the css code such that dynamically if their is no enough space at top to show the tooltip data it shows beneath.

Comment: Yeah is possible but i suggest to use some famous tooltips plugins such http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ for this purposes:)